# How to change Position of ReactToolTip

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

I am using `import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip'`

The problem is, I don't know how to change position of the tooltip. Is there any default function?

I want output like shown in the below image.

```
<ReactTooltip 
    id='notificationClickme' 
    place='right' 
    effect='solid' clickable={true}
    delayHide={500}
    delayShow={500}
    delayUpdate={500}
    place={'bottom'}
    border={true}
    isCapture ={true}
    type={'light'}
    ref= { el => this.tooltip = el}
>
</ReactTooltip>

<div id="notificationIcon" className="notification cursor-pointer" 
data-tip data-for='notificationClickme' data-event='click'>Notification icon image</div>
```

[currently i am getting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iILet.png)

[And ouput i want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlPQP.png)

Comment: have you tried `offset="left"` or right?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers about offset, there is also an `overridePosition` method that can be used, see [documentation on github](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip).

I use this method to recalculate position of a large (as in having big content) custom tooltip like this;

```
interface Position { left: number; top: number; }
const calculateNewPosition = (pos: Position): Position => {
    const newPosition = { top: window.innerHeight < topOverrideTreshold ? 120 : pos.top, left: window.innerWidth < 440 ? 10 : pos.left };
    return newPosition;
};

return (
    <ReactTooltip
        id={id}
        type="light"
        effect="solid"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        className="custom-tooltip"
        isCapture
        border
        overridePosition={calculateNewPosition}
    >
        <span className="header-container">
            <img src={informationCircle} className="header-icon" />
            <span>{header}</span>
            {isMobile || isTablet ? <span className="stb-sprite-small remove close-icon" onClick={onHide} aria-hidden="true" /> : ""}
        </span>
        <p>{firstParagraph}</p>
    </ReactTooltip>
);
```

In my specific case I make sure that the tooltip displays as expected on small (mobile) devices.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the offset property:

```
offset = "{'left': 60}"
```

Comment: `offset` is an object, not a string. It's declared as `offset = {{ left: -80 }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't apply that offset thing, there is a workaround:

Inspect DOM for react tooltip, you can find this class on a react tooltip div:

```
class="__react_component_tooltip place-top type-dark cp-tooltip"
```

Step 1 - add 'show' to class params so tooltip is permanently open and you can experiment with it:

```
class="__react_component_tooltip show place-top type-dark cp-tooltip"
```

Step 2 - do it by CSS, like this:

```
.__react_component_tooltip.place-top:after {
left: 89%;
}
```

where that percentage is arbitrary, depending on your needs (may be 'right' too, play with it).

Answer (score -1):

I think you missing the offset attribute on the element. see the code below.

```
<ReactTooltip id='notificationClickme' place='right' effect='solid' clickable={true}
                        effect='solid'
                        delayHide={500}
                        delayShow={500}
                        delayUpdate={500}
                        place={'bottom'}
                        border={true}
                        isCapture ={true}
                        type={'light'}
                        ref= { el => this.tooltip = el}
                        >

                    </ReactTooltip>


<div id="notificationIcon" className="notification cursor-pointer" data-tip data-for='notificationClickme' data-event='click' data-offset='left' > Notification icon image</div>
```

Comment: yeah i already tried , after adding  offset="left", tooltip is not opening. I dont know why

Comment: i am getting follwoing error, when i click on div to open tooltip.------------>SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON datagetPosition.js:262
    calculateOffset getPosition.js:262
    default getPosition.js:22
    showTooltip index.js:432
    showTooltip self-hosted:876
    checkStatus customEvent.js:86
    checkStatus self-hosted:920

Comment: I have changed the answer above, see the div for `data-offset` according to their API documentation that should do the trick, (I have not tested it) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

Comment: yeah i am using it (data-offset="{'left':70}"). But it doesnt point to same position in different resolution. I have to apply media css.